# null values in redis throws a deprecated warning

Tags: node.js, redis

Adding null values in redis hashes throws a deprecated warning
Description of the warning :

> node_redis: Deprecated: The HMSET command contains a "null" argument.
>   This is converted to a "null" string now and will return an error from
>   v.3.0 on. Please handle this in your code to make sure everything
>   works as you intended it to.

As redis is converts everything to string, what is the best way to enter null values into redis hashes and also retrieving it back ?

Comment: You don't need to put null values to `Maps` unless there's a specific reason to. If you fetch a key which does not exists then redis will return a `null` value automatically. If you still want to you can yourself insert `"null"` strings and redis will not give any error.